# How do I access camera code from other classes and reuse later on?

Tags: swift, xcode, camera

I have some code that accesses a `UIImagePickerController` and saves it in an image. I don't want to rewrite this every time I want to use it, so how else can I write this? Forgive me, I've only started this up as a hobby once again.

```
func startCamera(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: For example, you could use UIActionSheet. Try this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/swift-access-ios-camera-and-photo-library-dc1dbe0cdd76)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a extension of `UIViewController`, then you can access it in any `UIViewController` by calling `startCamera()`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let imagePicker = startCamera() {
            imagePicker.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // do something
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func startCamera() -> UIImagePickerController? {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return imagePicker
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but doesn't seem to call func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) after

Comment: Please see my revised answer. You have to return the `ImagePickerViewController` to your `UIViewController` to set the delegate.